# Most efficient way of calling mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, performance

Recently, I have been moving all of my 'mysql specific' functions into a class, just so if in the future I decided to switch DB languages, I woudn't have to correct all of my scripts, but just one class.

My question is about efficiency and speed on large data.

For example, now in my database.class.php I have:

```
public function fetchAssociative($data) {
    $assocarr = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
        array_push($assocarr, $row);
    }
    return $assocarr;
}
```

which then gets called in my script.

In compare to when I just use

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //operate on returned data ONE ROW AT A TIME
}
```

right in my script.

Now as I mentioned before, it is convenient to have all mysql specific functions in one class, but what about speed efficiency? In this example my script has to wait for all the data to get returned before doing any operations where as before (using while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) operations where done one at a time on each row returned.

TLDR: How are the efficiency and speed affected if I push mysql specific functions back into a class?

Comment: @AmalMurali I already am.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is about efficiency and speed on large data.

Then you should worry about SQL queries and indexing. 
Not PHP classes or PHP functions.. 98% off performance issues with MySQL and Big Data (read large datasets) are caused by inefficient SQL queries like subqueries, IN/EXISTS statements no indexing, wrong indexing, using joins without indexes and not understanding the MySQL engine..

Answer (score 0):

You should have **two** functions, not one.

```
public function fetch($result, $method = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result, $method);
}

public function fetchAll($result, $method = MYSQLI_ASSOC) {
    $ret = array();
    while (mysqli_fetch_array($result, $method)){
        $ret[] = $row;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

- in case you need all your data at once - call `fetchAll()`
- in case you need only one row or there are too much rows returned - use `fetch()` once/in a while loop respectively.